# Reading a huge file which has whole data in single line from remote host using paramiko

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to read a file from a remote host which has only one line. 
The data will be something like this:

```
{
   cid: {
      "mydom": ["abs", "abc"],
      "adom": ["abss", "abcv"],
      "bsom": ["avbs", "abvc"]
   },
   bid: {
      "madom": ["abs", "abc"],
      "asddom": ["abs", "abc"],
      "dasdom": ["abs", "abc"]
   }
}
```

The data is all in the same line but the size of the file is ~180 mb
I tried using paramiko's SFTP client but the function is taking lot of time to read all the data in this file.

This is what I have tried:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()

client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

client.connect(hostname = host_ip, username = user_name, pkey = key)

sftp_client = client.open_sftp()

my_file = sftp_client.open(file_name, mode='r',bufsize=500)
```

I tried the buffer size as well but it doesn't seem to be taking effect.
Any help on how to buffer this file or how to read this file faster is highly appreciated.

Comment: What's the performace ratio compared against the copy of this file with the "scp" command ? If scp is much faster, you should consider to make a local copy of this remote file in a temporary dir then parse the file in that temporary dir. Have a look at the "get" and "getfo" methods od SFTPClint objects that mimic "scp". http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.2/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.get

Comment: how much time do you mean by *taking lot of time*?

Comment: @whjm it takes more than an hour or so to read the file.

Comment: @glenfant with scp it takes less than a minute, I am doing the same (scp and reading a local copy) as a backup but i wanted to know if there is any better way to do it (without saving a local copy)

Comment: paramiko should not take too long compared to scp command. please post your full code.

Comment: @manojprashantk , I think the fastest and easiest way to do it is to make a temporary local copy and play with it. It should be easy to make a context manager that makes this copy, provides a handle to this file, then deletes the local copy on closing.